# LINQ select into object

Tags: c#

How can I box the result of a LINQ select into multiple objects? With the following select clause:

```
  select new {
        Person = new Person((String)al.Element("firstName"), (String)al.Element("lastName")),
        TimePeriod = new TimePeriod((String)al.Element("start"), (String)al.Element("end"))     
    };
```

In the example snippet above, Person and TimePeriod are totally unreleated object. Coming from a Scala background, I would have been happy if the result would be boxed into a tuple. Since I'm new to C#, can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Not sure what you mean, but you can create a class with those two properties and use `new ClassName`, or use the `Tuple` class.

Comment: There is [Tuple<T,K>](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd387181(v=vs.110).aspx) in C#, although I try to avoid it, as it reduces readability, better to create separate class for that if anonymous does not suit your needs.

Comment: Creating a new Class for just the sake of combining those two parameters seems not a good idea!

Comment: Anonymous types are meant to be short-lived data structures. Placing unrelated data in them is acceptable to me.

Comment: @user3102968: what if you want to put is outside the boundary of a method. How meaningful do you think `Tuple<string, int, long, object, List<string>>` is? I prefer a meaningful class name.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to put them into a `Tuple` you can do this

```
select Tuple.Create(new Person(...), new TimePeriod(...));
```

But it would be more advisable to create your own class

```
public class PersonAndTime
{
    public PersonAndTime(Person person, TimePeriod timePeriod)
    {
        Person = person;
        TimePeriod = timePeriod;
    } 
    public Person Person{ get; private set; }
    public TimePeriod TimePeriod {get; private set; }
}
```

And do this

```
select new PersonAndTime(new Person(...), new TimePeriod(...));
```

If you don't need to pass the results of the query into or out of a method then leaving it in the anonymous class should be fine.